# Windows Clipboard Read Notification

Tags: windows, clipboard

Is there any way for a Windows application to get notified when another application reads from the clipboard? I would like to emphasize -- not when the clipboard content changes, but when any another application reads it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Delayed Rendering.  You'll receive a WM_RenderFormat when an application pastes the data into itself.  (Update: But you don't know if any OTHER apps have pasted that same data. Once WM_RenderFormat has been satisfied, there are no further notifications if other apps paste that same data, using the same format. e.g. CF_TEXT).

Of course, this applies to ANY application, so you'll be notified when clipboard mangers, virtual machines, remote desktop, etc., sync the clipboard between workspaces.

See: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649014(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Delayed_Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Delayed_Rendering)

Update: After clarification from the OP that he needs to know about clipboard reads when his app is neither the provider or consumer, then the answer for that situation is NO.  It is not possible for a "neutral 3rd-party observer app" to know which specific apps have pasted data.

Comment: As I see, this allows my application to get notified when any application reads the clipboard content provided by my application itself. What I really wanted is to get notified when any application reads the clipboard no matter who placed anything there, in a monitoring manner. This means that I would receive something like "Application A (not necessarily mine) put [data] to the clipboard", "Application B read [data] from the clipboard" and so on.